# The exact meaning of "we have to get Regal Escrow their refund"

Tags: meaning

> we have to get Regal Escrow their refund by five.

Hello, I am an English learner and I am confused the meaning of this sentence.
Does it means we have to get refund from Regal Escrow? 
or we have to refund Regal Escrow?

Answer (score 3):

*Regal Escrow* will be receiving a refund.

*We* are the ones who have to make sure they get it by five.

That much is clear. "Their" refers to Regal Escrow, and "their refund" means the refund owed to them.

What is not clear from that one sentence is where the refund is coming from. Taken out of context, it could mean any of the following:

- *We* are the ones who owe Regal Escrow a refund, and *we* will pay them. Or
- Some third party owes Regal Escrow a refund, and *we* are acting on Regal Escrow's behalf to make sure it happens. (In this scenario perhaps we are lawyers or brokers.) Or
- Some third party owes Regal Escrow a refund, and *we* are acting on the third party's behalf to facilitate the transaction. (In this scenario perhaps *we* are the third party's bank.)

Answer (score 0):

"Regal Escrow" is a third person proper noun. "We" is a first person pronoun. "Their" is a third person possessive pronoun. If we are to analyse using the possible 'subjects' or entities in the sentence, **the entity 'we' should get Regal Escrow's refund by five.**

Also, take note of the general pattern "... give/get + X + [possessive pronoun for X] + Y."

e.g., Give Orion his belt. (OR)
Give him (Orion) his belt.

Get the tourists their visas. (OR) Get them (the tourists) their visas.

Answer (score -2):

It means exactly you want Regal Escrow to refund you by 5 o'clock

Comment: I agree nnnnnn's idea. But thanks for your answer